# How to redirect traffic from specific IP to localhost using iptables

Tags: linux, redirect, ssh, firewall, iptables

I have executable and it tries to connect to `10.5.5.100:22` (ssh) address which does not exist. I want to redirect that traffic to `localhost:22` using `iptables`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se], [su], or [sf].

Answer (score 2):

Use the REDIRECT target:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.5.5.100 --dport 22 -j REDIRECT
```

This will send the packets back to your primary network interface.

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables